# Is there a way to switch the Capslock and Tab keys on OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, hotkeys, keystrokes

I'm looking for a way to totally remap the Tab and Capslock key. That is, pressing Capslock sends the keycode for Tab, and pressing Tab sends the keycode for Capslock. Is this possible on OS x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try keyboard-maestro or PCKeyboard-Hack.